# Cakephp input date value no getting in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, cakephp

I have a input field of type date

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Order',
array('action'=>'fixedFormAllOrders','type'=>'post'));?>
         <table>
         <tr>
       <td ><?php  echo $this->Form->input('search',
          arra    ('label'=>'Search By','type'=>'select','id'=>'search',
 'empty'=>'--select--','options' =>array     ('new'=>'New Orders',
  'pending'=>'Pending             orders','past'=>'Delivered/Past Orders',
'viewall'=>'View All Orders'))); ?></td>
     <td style="width:60px;" >
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('order_date',
      array(                                                                             'type'  => 'date', 'label' =>
    'Search By Date',                                                                         'id'=>'date' )); echo $this->Form->Submit        ('Search',array('id'=>'submit_date'));?></td>

      and when I try to access the value from jquery, it is showing Undefined.

         $order_date= $('#date').val();
         alert($order_date);
```

so how to get value of date field in jquery. if anybody know please help me

Comment: Can you share the html?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the input type as `date` should generate 3 select boxes (for month, day and year).
Use

```
echo $this->Form->input('order_date', array('id' => 'orderDate', 'type'  => 'date', 'label' => 'Search By Date'));
```

The the values will be:

```
var orderDay = $('#orderDateDay').val();
var orderMonth = $('#orderDateMonth').val();
var orderYear = $('#orderDateYear').val();
alert($orderYear + '-' + orderMonth + '-' + orderDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          //getting the value of day
        $order_day=$('.input.date select[name$="[day]"]').val();
          //getting the value of month
         $order_month=$('.input.date select[name$="[month]"]').val();
            //getting the value of year

         $order_year=$('.input.date select[name$="[year]"]').val();
```